# What do I get for not making deals with Satan?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac-rebirth

In Binding of Isaac (both Rebirth and the original), you can make deals with the Devil, where you trade your hearts for items (you can also get Angel rooms, which give you a rare item, but that is besides the point for now). What can I gain from NOT taking a deal with the Devil and ignoring his items?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The obvious advantage is not taking the deal means you don't lose any heart containers. Having more health makes you more likely to survive, or saves the hearts for a later devil room.

The other advantage is that not taking the items gives you a chance of receiving angel rooms. If you would receive a devil room on a floor after visiting the devil room on the previous floor without buying anything, there is a chance of an angel room.